# C++ multi data text parse via regex

Tags: c++, regex, stringstream

Text to be parsed:

```
001  B001C001_230130_RQ7V V     C        04:23:30:18 04:24:14:01 01:00:00:00 01:00:43:08  
*ASC_SOP (1.000000 1.000000 1.000000)(0.000000 0.000000 0.000000)(1.000000 1.000000 1.000000)
*ASC_SAT 1.000000
```

I'm trying to parse the *ASC_SOP triplets into 3x float[3] arrays.

The source file is loaded and passed to a `parse()` function line by line. The current function looks like this:

```
inline void parse(std::string &line) {

    //regex to match edl id's camera reel and slope values
    std::regex edlID("^([0-9]{3})");
    std::regex camReel("([A-Za-z]([0-9]{3}))\\S+");
    std::regex SOP("(?:[0-9][.][0-9]{6})");

    std::smatch mID, reelID, sopMatch; //regex matchers

    //check if there is an edlID. As per CM3600 spec this is always the first column
    if(std::regex_search(line, mID, edlID)) {
        std::regex_search(line, reelID, camReel); //next we check for a clip/reel name combo
        std::cout << "EDL ID: " << mID[0] << " Clip: " << reelID[0] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to parse the *ASC_SOP values and the ASC_SAT values into a corresponding float? Is regex the best solution for this? or is a token based stringstream better? One thought I had would be to strip the line of all parenthesis and then iterate over again with a `' '` delimiter. Does anyone have an efficient way to process this?

Comment: Use regex to parse into strings then use std::stof (or std::stod) to convert to float (note a good way is to develop/dewbug your regexes here first : https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that the lines you care about here always follow the same basic pattern: `*ASC_SOP` followed by three groups of parens, each containing three floating point numbers, I'd probably use a `stringstream`. For a case like this, I usually start with a little fixed-pattern matcher<sup>1</sup>:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, char const *pat) {
    while (is.peek() == *pat) {
        ++pat;
        is.ignore(1);
    }
    if (*pat)
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    return is;
}
```

With this, we can do the matching something like this:

```cpp
    float a[3], b[3], c[3];

    if (input >> "*ASC_SOP (" >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2] >> ")(" 
                              >> b[0] >> b[1] >> b[2] >> ")(" 
                              >> c[0] >> c[1] >> c[2] >> ")") 
    {
        std::cout << "parsed ASC_SOP\n";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Attempt at parsing ASC_SOP failed\n";
    }
```

Although the pattern matcher itself isn't entirely intuitive, at least to me, it seems like it makes the rest of the code quite clear and understandable (and once you understand what it's intended to accomplish, the pattern matcher isn't particularly difficult either).

---

1. Depending on the situation, it can make sense to make this a little more elaborate, such as if the streams `skipws` flag is set, have it match any whitespace in the pattern with an arbitrary amount of whitespace in the input stream, like happens in the formst string for `scanf` and company. That could be useful if (for example) there might or might not be a space (or possibly tab) between a closing paren the the next opening paren. But once you have the basic idea it's pretty easy to add things like that if needed.

Comment: This is good, thanks. Is the concept behind this rooted in operator overloading? It's not something I am familiar with, so will need to look into it to fully understand.

I've tried to modify your usage example `if` statement to account for the `*ASC_SAT` value but it doesn't seem to be working. I have tried the following `if(sourceline_stringstream >> "*ASC_SAT " >> targetFloat){...}` but it doesn't seem to return a value. I've tried with the `skipws` flag and removing the space in the if statement.

Comment: Yes, this is an overloaded operator.

Comment: any ideas why i can't get the sat value using the same method?

Comment: @hdcdigi: No, at least not without seeing the code. There aren't a lot of obvious differences between the two.